# pandas dataframe : how to update specific rows in hive table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, hive

I want to update a single column in a hive table. Here is how i am selecting the data

```
from datetime import timedelta, date
import pandas as pd
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext,HiveContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import os
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("job1").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()


test1=spark.sql("""
select * from myPartitionedTable
where part1='adqwf' and 
      part2='avgewg' and
      col2='filter_condition'
""")

import pandas as pd
import json
import urllib.parse
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
pandasDF = test1.toPandas()
smvr={}

for index, row in pandasDF.iterrows():
    newpr = []
    pr = pandasDF.iloc[index]['col1']
    if pr:
        
        for p in pr:
            newp = p.asDict()
            newp['attribute1']=p.attribute1+'_suffix'
            newpr.append(newp)
        print(newpr[0])
        pandasDF.iloc[index]['attribute1'][0]=newpr[0]
        print(pandasDF.iloc[index]['attribute1'][0])
        
        break
```

so with the above snippet, i am able to see that

`print(pandasDF.iloc[index]['attribute1'][0])`

has the updated value. Now, how can i update the underlying hive table as well? I was going through some resources online and the following suggestions appeared

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode","dynamic")
data.write.mode("overwrite").insertInto("partitioned_table")
```

this could work but note that in my select query i have

```
      col2='filter_condition'
```

so basically i dont want to overwrite the entire partition, but only the rows that i have selected.

Is that possible with the above approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* I understand this right, but I am unable to test it. Let me know how this works.

You need to modify your code to update the `pd.DataFrame` with the new values, and then convert the updated `pd.DataFrame` back to a `Spark DataFrame` using the `createDataFrame()` method of the `SparkSession`.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType

# Define the schema of your DataFrame
schema = StructType([
    StructField("col1", StringType()),
    StructField("attribute1", StringType()),
    StructField("products", StringType()),
    StructField("part1", StringType()),
    StructField("part2", StringType())
])

# Create a new DataFrame with the updated values
updated_df = spark.createDataFrame(
    pandasDF,
    schema=schema
).withColumn("products", col("products").cast("array<struct<attribute1:string,attribute2:string>>"))

# Enable dynamic partition overwrite mode
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic")

# Overwrite only the selected rows in your Hive table
updated_df.write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("part1", "part2").format("hive").saveAsTable("myPartitionedTable")
```

Comment: thanks, but will the above only update the selected/filtered rows? or will it overwrite the entire partition?

Comment: This should overwrite only the selected rows since those are what is contained in `updated_df`. I don't have a way to test on your data, but with what I have this seems to work.